# Making data partition default partition

Tags: command-line, directory, default

Recently I installed Ubuntu and Fedora on my system.

Each OS has its own partition and I made a data partition to save my personal files.

Now in Ubuntu when I open terminal its default location is Ubuntu's home folder
but I want to change it to data partition. I also want to change my home directory. I mean when I type `cd ~` I want to go to data partition.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

I want new applications to default to the data partition not in my old home. And also change all folders location in home like Music, Downloads, etc to data partition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Prerequisites

**Finding the UUID of the partition**

Run this command in the terminal

```
sudo blkid
```

You will get something like this

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="FA286F4C286F06CB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="328E-CDB6" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="7programs" UUID="01CAB88B789D7370" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="TempBAKUP" UUID="EF54-7F8C" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="B62A57642A5720A3" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="7programs" UUID="01CAB88B789D7370" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Find the data partition that you made earlier and note down the UUID

**Making sure that the partition mounts at bootime**

**Duplicate your fstab file:**

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

**Open the original fstab in a text editor:**

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

and add these lines into it

```
# (identifier)  (location, eg sda5)   (format, eg ext3 or ext4)      (some settings) 
UUID=????????   /media/home    ext4          nodev,nosuid       0       2
```

and replace the "????????" with the UUID number of the intended /home partition found above.

---

## Using Usermod

Use this command to just change the homedir

```
usermod -d /media/home username
```

replace `username` with your username

Now move all of the files in `/home/` to `/media/home/` with this command:

```
cd / && sudo mv /home/* /media/home
```

Now, delete the old home folder

```
sudo rmdir /home --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
```

---

*Sources:*

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1294/Unix-/-Linux-change-a-user%27s-home-directory---usermod

Comment: Very helpful answer. An alternative to using usermod would be to copy the data as above, and then change the fstab entry to mount the partition on /home rather than on /media/home (and then reboot).

Comment: @JohnSGruber Look at the edit history. I deleted that part for simplicity